# Reset integers in a TextView to 0 (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, reset

So I got the increment and decrement buttons work, but I need to reset the second set to 0 using the clear button. If you push it, it'll show you a 0 as a string value, but it won't reset the output. For example if I we're to increment the integer values up to 6 and then push the clear button, it'll show 0 in the TextView but once I push the increment button again it'll go straight up to 7 and not 1.

What am I missing?

KT

```
package com.example.plus_and_minus_input

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    increase_1.setOnClickListener { increaseInteger1() }
    decrease_1.setOnClickListener { decreaseInteger1()

    }



    increase_2.setOnClickListener { increaseInteger2() }
    decrease_2.setOnClickListener { decreaseInteger2() }

    clear_button.setOnClickListener {
        integer_number_2.text ="0"
    }


}
private var integer1 = 0
private var integer2 = 0

fun increaseInteger1() {
    //display_number_1(integer_number_1.text.toString().toInt() + 1)
    integer1 = (integer1 + 1).coerceAtMost(10)
    display_number_1(integer1)


}

fun decreaseInteger1() {
    //display_number_1(integer_number_1.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
    integer1 = (integer1 - 1).coerceAtLeast(0)
    display_number_1(integer1)



}


fun increaseInteger2() {
    //display_number_2(integer_number_2.text.toString().toInt() + 1)
    integer2 = (integer2 + 1).coerceAtMost(10)
    display_number_2(integer2)
}

fun decreaseInteger2() {
    //display_number_2(integer_number_2.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
    integer2 = (integer2 - 1).coerceAtLeast(0)
    display_number_2(integer2)
}



private fun display_number_1(number: Int) {
    integer_number_1.setText("$number")
}

private fun display_number_2(number: Int) {
    integer_number_2.setText("$number")
}

}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="309dp"
    android:layout_height="118dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="549dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decrease_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/integer_number_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="70sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/increase_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+" />


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/decrease_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/integer_number_2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.513"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.317" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/increase_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="+"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.579"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/integer_number_2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/integer_number_2"
    android:layout_width="46dp"
    android:layout_height="99dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="46dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="70sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.426"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.297" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/clear_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/integer_number_2" />


  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the value of the global int var also:

```
clear_button.setOnClickListener {
    integer_number_2.text ="0"
    integer2 = 0
}
```

It's bad practise to name your variables with underscores in kotlin/java. Use camel case instead `tvIntegerNumberTwo` and probably assign it the initials of the xml element type to better recognise what it is.